# Using persistence.xml to connect to MySQL database. Why is EntityManager query returning null?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entitymanager, apache-tomee

I am using Tomee 7.0 plus as my server. I am using persistence.xml to establish a connection to an online MySQL database using the jdbc:mysql driver. I am using the EntityManager that I receive from the connection, and injecting that into my class, UserManager, where I am running queries. 
I am out of solutions why my queries are not hitting my actual table in my database. The error I keep getting is a nullpointer. Is there something wrong with my persistence.xml? Because it doesn't seem to be establishing a full connection...

I am not using Maven, or Spring, or Hibernate. I am in a group project, and I am trying to get this database up and running and would really appreciate any input or idea why my connection isn't established.

Here is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="UserService" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>userDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <class>edu.neumont.pro280.models.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://mywebsite.com/trivitup" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="trivitup" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I inject the connection to my UserManager and I get null when I print out the currentUser.
This is the UserManager class I use to inject the connection:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UserService")
    EntityManager em;

    public User findUserByUsername(String user) {
    System.out.println("User to find is: " + user);
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username=:user", User.class);
    query.setParameter("user", user);

    List<User> userList = query.getResultList();
    User returnUser = null;
    System.out.println("list size: " + userList.size());
    if (userList.size() == 1) {
        for (User user1 : userList) {
            returnUser = user1;
        }
    }
    return returnUser;
}
```

I use a LoginServlet that will authenticate the user if the user was successfully retrieved. Below I get a null when I print out the currentUser's username.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = (String) req.getParameter("username");
        String password = (String) req.getParameter("password");
        User currentUser = userManager.findUserByUsername(username);
        System.out.println("This is currentUser... "
                + currentUser.getUsername());

    }
```

Thank you for any kind of idea or help.

Comment: `NullPointerException` **WHERE**?

Comment: @Isaac I guess that he gets it on em.createQuery(), because EntityManager is not injected.

Comment: Sorry, I am going to edit where I call the user to print out now.

Comment: @Isaac I do not get the null there. I get it when I call the UserManager class from a login servlet to authenticate if the user actually exists in my db or not.

Comment: `userList.size() < 2 && userList.size() > 0` aka `userList.size() == 1`

Comment: @CYen are you sure that you have any User inserted in the DB?

Comment: @fmodos yes, I am positive.

Comment: `"list size: " + userList.size()` what is the size of userList?

Comment: @fmodos the list size is 0.. kind of a hint that the user will be null

Comment: SELECT * FROM User - what does it return when executed on the DB directly, not from Java code?

Comment: When executing that query directly into the MySQL db I get the two test users I am testing with. However, interesting concept is, if I use A ServletContextListener and manually set the connection object, the Connection object is NOT null and I can run queries on it. SO I am almost positive my problem is something with my persistence.xml.. or my JPA

Comment: Can you try shutting down your database and running this program again? we need proof that the database that you're trying to access is indeed the database that you *think* you're accessing.

Comment: @Isaac I dropped the table I was trying to query with my original program and it still says there is a nullpointer at the same line.

Comment: @CYen Alright, so we know that the problem is not with your query at all; it's with the JPA connection to the database. You said that it works when you construct the connection in the context listener. How do you construct it there?

Comment: @Isaac I've updated my question with the new bit of code.

Comment: @CYen He asked you about JPA connection. How did you configure and how did you use it with your application.

Comment: @CYen why are you specifying both `jta-data-source` and explicit connection properties? this might as well be your problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this solution is very interesting, and I still do not understand all of it. Everything is completely correct with my persistence.xml, that is the exact data someone would need to connect to a MySQL db, but still won't work. In order to solve this nullpointer issue, I had to extract the resource element from my persistence.xml and extract it into another document, called resources.xml, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <Resource id="userDataSource" type="DataSource">
   JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://mywebsite.com/trivitup
   UserName trivitup
   Password password
 </Resource>
</resources>
```

and after that, I had established db connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your error may have something to do with the fact that you provide both `jta-data-source` and explicit URL properties.

I'm guessing that what happens is that JPA is using the datasource that is bound to `userDataSource` in JNDI, instead of the datasource specified by the properties inside `persistence.xml`. You should doublecheck how you're defining the `userDataSource` data source, and preferably remove the explicit URL/username/password properties.

Comment: This didn't work. I'm sorry.. I must have some bad entity configuration.

Answer (score -1):

when Tomee start up, You can see the log of config JPA Persistence Unit. If there wasn't log about that, make sure your META-INF directory at the root class path.